# Validate new users passwords in Django admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-validation

There is one interesting moment in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation):

> By default, validators are used in the forms to reset or change passwords and in the createsuperuser and changepassword management commands. Validators aren’t applied at the model level, for example in User.objects.create_user() and create_superuser(), because we assume that developers, not users, interact with Django at that level and also because model validation doesn’t automatically run as part of creating models.

But in my Django app i am using only Django Admin interface with `admin.ModelAdmin`.
When i am trying to create new user i can broke all the validators from `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`.
How can i validate passwords on creating new users in Django admin interface using validators `AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`?

admin.py:

```
class UserCreateForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'password']


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = UserCreateForm
    list_display = ('username')

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
        if change:
            return self.change_form
        return super(UserAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return True

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return True

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if obj.pk:
            orig_obj = User.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
            if obj.password != orig_obj.password:
                obj.set_password(obj.password)
        else:
            obj.is_superuser = True
            obj.set_password(obj.password)
        obj.save()
```

models.py:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        validators=[username_validator]
        )

    objects = UserManager()
```

managers.py:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password=None):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have username assigned')
        user = self.model(username=username)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(username, password=password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    }
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Password validation was added in Django 1.9.

Comment: Alasdair, Django 2.0.6

Comment: Alasdair, to reproduce my problem i've done the same steps.

Comment: Alasdair, i have added all the code affects that problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs you have linked to say:

> By default, validators are used in the forms to reset or change passwords

For example, the `UserAdmin` uses the [`UserCreationForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/63f90f55f30d599d601d729060cdb0ebd2abdeb8/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L63), which validates the passwords.

You have your own `UserAdmin` and `UserCreateForm`, so the passwords will not be validated unless you add this functionality.

Think carefully about whether you really need to override `AbstractBaseUser`. If you override `AbstractUser` instead, then it will be easier to use/extend the built in forms/model admins, and you won't have to implement password validation yourself.

Answer (score 3):

**UPD from author of question:**
For everyone with same problem: you need to add that function to `UserCreateForm`:

```
def clean(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
    if password:
        try:
            password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)
        except forms.ValidationError as error:
            self.add_error('password', error)
```